# In spring boot, is there a pattern to put commonly needed data in a context?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my spring boot app, I need data like `timezone, locale, language` etc for each request the app serves.

Currently, each controller/handler is responsible for fetching this information on its own. Is there a way to put this information in a context of some sort so that we don't have to query for this information everytime in different places ? I wan't the flow to be like so:

1. Request received
2. My custom code to query the db and set these values on `MyContext`. These values should be accessible anywhere downstream.
3. Controllers, services, any other code which processes this request should be able to read these values like `MyContext.getTimeZone`, etc

Answer (score 0):

From the question it seems that information you need to store is different for each request. For that I'd use `request` scoped beans. Spring documentation for scopes [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-scopes.html).

I'll provide minimal example. We need to create a bean and then configure app to invoke some of its method before it'll reach controller layer.

#### MyContext (bean)

First we create a bean with request context.

```
@Service
@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyContext {
    // ...
}
```

New instance of this class will be created for each request.

### HandlerInterceptor

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MyHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final MyContext myContext;

    @Autowired
    public MyHandlerInterceptor(MyContext myContext) {
        this.myContext = myContext;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // your logic to set context
        myContext.setAnything();
        return true;
    }

    // ...
}
```

### Configuration

```java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private MyHandlerInterceptor myHandlerInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(myHandlerInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

This will register the interceptor we defined in previous stap and make sure `preHandle` is called before execution reaches your controller.

Instead of HandlerInterceptors we could use [filters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html) to achieve basically the same.